# An application of Cauchy integral formula with pole on boundary

Tags: contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

How to use Cauchy integral formula to solve the following problem:
$$
\oint_{|z-1|=3}\frac{dz}{z(z^2-4)e^z
}
$$

Comment: The integral diverges. Did you mean a principal value ? In that case look at the [mean value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation) $\frac{1}{2}(\int_{|z-1| = 3 +\epsilon}f(z)dz+\int_{|z-1| = 3 -\epsilon}f(z)dz)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\oint_{(\text{C})}\frac{dz}{z(z^2-4)e^z}=\oint_{(\text{C})}\frac{dz}{z(z-2)(z+2)e^z}
$$

[image]

Residue at $z=0$
$$Res_1=\frac{1}{(0-2)(0+2)e^0}=-\frac{1}{4}$$

Residue at $z=-2$
$$Res_2=\frac{1}{(-2)(-2-2)e^{-2}}=\frac{e^2}{8}$$
Since the pole $z=-2$ is turned around of half a spin, the total residue is :
$$Res=Res_1+\frac{1}{2}Res_2=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{e^2}{8})=\frac{e^2-4}{16}$$
$$
\oint_{(\text{C})}\frac{dz}{z(z^2-4)e^z}=2\pi i Res=\pi i\frac{e^2-4}{8}$$

IN ADDITION , explanation :

On the small semi-circle $(\gamma)\quad\to\quad z=-2+\epsilon\:e^{i\theta}$, the integration leads to : $\oint_{(\gamma)}\frac{dz}{z(z^2-4)e^z}=\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{i e^{i\theta}d\theta}{z(z^2-4)e^z}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2}\frac{i e^{i\theta}d\theta}{z(z^2-4)e^z}=\frac{1}{2}(2\pi i Res_2)=\pi i Res_2$

The integral on the external contour $(\text{C})+(\gamma)$ is equal to the contribution of the poles inside :
$$\oint_{(\text{C})}\frac{dz}{z(z^2-4)e^z}+\pi i Res_2=2\pi iRes_1+2\pi iRes_2$$
Which is the justification of the above result :
$$\oint_{(\text{C})}\frac{dz}{z(z^2-4)e^z}=2\pi i\left(Res_1+\frac{1}{2}Res_2\right)$$

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!